# add and remove classes by jquery to auto generated div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a set of auto-generated divs by js.
I need to apply some CSS rules by jquery so If clicked on one of them the other become deactivated and on clicking it again the other back to activation.

I know the CSS attributes and I already prepared some classes for the different modes but what I need to know how can I do this for auto-generated divs with serial IDs.

```
<div class="row">
 <div id="1_1" class="avilable"> box 01 </div>
 <div id="1_2" class="avilable"> box 01 </div>
 <div id="1_3" class="avilable"> box 01 </div>
 <div id="1_4" class="avilable"> box 01 </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
 <div id="2_1" class="avilable"> box 01 </div>
 <div id="2_2" class="avilable"> box 01 </div>
 <div id="2_3" class="avilable"> box 01 </div>
 <div id="2_4" class="avilable"> box 01 </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
 <div id="3_1" class="avilable"> box 01 </div>
 <div id="3_2" class="avilable"> box 01 </div>
 <div id="3_3" class="avilable"> box 01 </div>
 <div id="3_4" class="avilable"> box 01 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this jquery code:-

```
$("body").on("click","div.avilable",function(){
    $("div.avilable").removeClass("test-remove");
    $(this).addClass("test-add");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this - Jquery

```
$("body").on("click","div.avilable",function(){
    $("div.avilable").removeClass("active");
$(this).addClass("active");
```

})

here is jsfiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/8upt4e2s/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div.avilable").on("click",function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```